# Create a theme style dynamically in an android application

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm looking for a solution to create a theme style dynamically in an android app. Our customer make there styles in an back office and from the application we retrieve this information. With this info's we wan't to update the current theme or create a new one. But we didn't found a way to do this because we can't add or change a data in sytle.xml or R class during running app.

I don't want to modify element by element on loading page in code like this `textViewStyleDynamic.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)`.

It would be perfect to edit or create a theme dynamically and set it on the app.

Comment: you already said it. It's not possible. What are you really asking?

Comment: A solution to do this properly ? There is inevitably another solutionn than modify element by element on loading page